# Проблема со сравнением значений объектов через equals

Tags: java

Почему в данном случае не происходит сравнения значений объектов?

```
for (int l = 0; l < edges_count; ++l)
        {
            if (var2.getModel().getValue(values_edges_new[l]).equals(null)==true)
            {
                no_value_edges.add(vk, edges_mass[l]);
                ++vk;
            }
        }
```

var2.getModel().getValue(values_edges_new[l]) возвращает объект со значением null, но условие цикла тупо не выполняется. Не выполняется оно и в это случае

```
    if (var2.getModel().getValue(values_eges.get(k)).equals("1") == false)
```

Помогите, давно мучаюсь :С

Comment: Во-первых, если бы  `getValue()` вернул `null`, вы бы получили `NullPointerException`. Во-вторых, на `null` проверяют обычным равенством.

Comment: Собсна, при выводе на печать объекта, который возвращает getValue()  у меня выводит null

Comment: Значит у этого объекта метод `toString()` возвращает строку "null", но сам он `null` не равен.

Comment: зачем в блоке if проводить сравнение с true? если выражение будет true, оно и так выполнит условный блок, без всяких очевидных сравнений с true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если объект у Вас действительно должен быть null, то как правильно было замечено в комментариях выше объекты нужно просто сравнивать через "==". Если же объект не обязательно должен быть null, то Вам следует в классе объекта переопределить метод equals()